# Android List View Limited Height

Tags: android, xml

I have a XML layout that consists of seven textview and spinners, under the spinners and textview I have a listview that is causing the problems. The list view is set to wrap content but it only has a height of 1 row and no matter what weight or height I give it it remains the same size.

Can some one point out where I am going wrong?

**XML**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout2">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="?actionBarSize"
        android:paddingBottom="?actionBarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/monday"
        android:text="Monday's Recipe: "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mondayRecipe"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/monday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/mondaySpinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/monday"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"></Spinner>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tuesday"
                android:text="Tuesday's Recipe: "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tuesdayRecipe"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tuesday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/tuesdaySpinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tuesday"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"></Spinner>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wednesday"
                android:text="Wednesday's Recipe: "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wednesdayRecipe"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wednesday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/wednesdaySpinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/wednesday"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"></Spinner>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/thursday"
                android:text="Thursday's Recipe: "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/thursdayRecipe"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thursday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/thursdaySpinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thursday"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"></Spinner>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/friday"
                android:text="Friday's Recipe: "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fridayRecipe"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/fridaySpinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/friday"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"></Spinner>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/saturday"
                android:text="Saturday's Recipe: "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/saturdayRecipe"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/saturday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/saturdaySpinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/saturday"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"></Spinner>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sunday"
                android:text="Sunday's Recipe: "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sundayRecipe"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sunday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sundaySpinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sunday"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"></Spinner>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/required"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sundaySpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/weeklyList"
            android:layout_below="@+id/required"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            ></ListView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addButton"
                android:text="Add"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cancelButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.rory.pocketchef.Fragments.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: show mobile screen image so one can get better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `android:fillViewport="true"` in the scrollview.
hope this will resolved your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I do actually have one more question if you dont mind. So when the list becomes populated the two buttons in the relative layout at the bottom disappear, do you know why this would happen? They are there before anything is added to the list

Comment: Give appropriate Weight property to relative layout as well.